# Index of a pattern in a String vector with missing values in Julia

Tags: string, julia, missing-data

I am attempting to retrieve the index of all instances of a pattern in a String vector with missing values.

E.g. How can I get a vector with the index of all instances containing the pattern `"a"` from:

```
x = ["ab", "ca", "bc", missing, "ad"]
```

The desired outcome would be equal to:

```
Vector([1, 2, 5])
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 5
```

As these are the indexes in which the pattern appears.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A natural way to write it is:

```
julia> findall(v -> ismissing(v) ? false : contains(v, "a"), x)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 5
```

Alternatively you could write:

```
julia> using Missings

julia> findall(coalesce.(passmissing(contains).(x, "a"), false))
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 5
```

which in this case is less readable, but in other contexts you might find `passmissing` and `coalesce` useful so I mention them.

Answer (score 1):

The `findall` version can be even neater:

```
julia> findall(contains("a"), skipmissing(x))
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 2
 5
```

The first cool thing about this is that `contains` returns a curried version of itself, when supplied only the pattern to search for. So here, the `contains("a")` returns a function that searches for `"a"` inside any given String argument, and we pass that function on to `findall` as the predicate.

Even cooler is the way `skipmissing` works. As the name indicates, it skips `missing` values in its argument, but it doesn't just filter them out from `x` (which would change the indices of all values after the `missing`s), but by providing an iterator that just jumps past the `missing` values. This means that the indices `findall` returns by iterating `skipmissing(x)` will be valid for `x` too, which is exactly what we want.